# Does Central Limit Theorem implies that ...

Tags: statistics, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_1$, $X_2$, ... be iid random variables with $E(X_1)$ = $\mu < \infty$ and $Var(X_1)$ = $\sigma^2 < \infty$.

Does the Central Limit Theorem implies that the sample mean converges in distribution to a normally distributed random variable?

Also, does the theorem implies that the sample mean is a consistent estimator for $\mu$?

Comment: Is there any difference between your question 1 and your question 2?

Comment: Oppss.. I've amended my question!

Comment: Sample mean converges to a degenerate $N(\mu,0)$ - which is LLN and implies consistency of the estimator. CLT states that properly *scaled* sample mean converges to $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and you can derive (weak) LLN from CLT.

Comment: @A.S. Actually, the CLT establishes the convergence to a *centered* normal random variable, not to $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ (except if $\mu=0$).